# React-native release build causes emulator to have "System UI isnt responding" error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, android-emulator

I am building an app using react-native and android emulator on my development platform.  My project centers around the react-native-track-player along with other packages in the project.   As I wrapped up the development, I performed the last debug/dev build and tested fine on the android emuator with no issues using ths command:
> react-native run-android

The flow completes fine, loads the app into the emulatr and starts it -- the app works fine.

However when I create the release variant,  the build process completes fine, but upon starting the app on the android emulator, a message "System UI isnt responding" message window ops up on the emulator, upon closing the window.  any interaction with the app is non responsive.  in my case the 'play button' does not play.  I did not get this issue during the debug/dev build.

The release build command I usde:

> react-native run-android --variant=release

I am not sure what kind of additional information the experts here want to know and want me to post here.  So I will start with react-native info details:

```
$ react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries 
information...
(node:5812) Warning: Accessing non-existent 
property 'padLevels' of module exports inside 
circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where 
the warning was created)
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 
2.50GHz
Memory: 6.10 GB / 11.86 GB
 Binaries:
Node: 14.8.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.22.5 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
npm: 6.14.7 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
Android SDK:
  API Levels: 23, 29, 30
  Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.1, 30.0.2
  System Images: android-30 | Google APIs Intel
```

x86 Atom
Android NDK: Not Found
Windows SDK:
AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
AllowAllTrustedApps: Enabled
Versions: 10.0.19041.0
IDEs:
Android Studio: Version  4.0.0.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
Visual Studio: Not Found
Languages:
Java: 1.8.0_261 - /c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261/bin/javac
Python: 3.8.6 - /c/Users/Bryon/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
react-native: 0.63.2 => 0.63.2